# css want p to have width less than max width when set

Tags: css

I need to set `width` or `max-width` in order for `margin:auto` to work, right? [Like in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H7qrp/1/).

Trouble is, the paragraph width is equal to `max-width` and so the block of text is not properly centered.

How can I make the width of the paragraph contract to be only *just* big enough to contain the text, expanding to `max-width` as necessary?

No javascript and no fixed widths. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add any extra markup?

Comment: I believe a paragraph tag will automatically be sized to 100% of the container's width, unless you manually set the max-size as shown in the jsFiddle. I assume it isn't possible to horizontally auto-size the paragraph tag to the text that is in it.

But is there a reason you want to use a paragraph for this? In this case, wouldn't it be easier to simply use another div? They are a lot less hard to style, and have more ways to work with them. Static AND dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but maybe an `inline-block` paragraph is what you're looking for:

```
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>​
```

```css
div { text-align: center; }
p { display: inline-block; text-align: left; max-width: 40ex; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wuqaH/1/

Comment: Yes; if the text itself needs to be left-aligned simply set `text-align: left` within `p`. Although `max-width: 40ex` is left out of this fiddle, you can keep it as in the original fiddle and the constraint will still work.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock, added your suggestions to the answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to set a max-width / or a width in percentage ?

It would be like that :

> ```
> div {
>     width: 100%;
>     background: red;
> }
>
> p {
>     margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
>     background: blue;
>     max-width: 90%; }
> ```

you can try it on your jsFiddle.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to center the text in p, why not use `text-align:center;` property

http://jsfiddle.net/H7qrp/5/